# How to write Semigroup instance for this data type?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do one of the Semigroup exercises in [Haskell Book](http://haskellbook.com/) (Chapter 15, "Monoid, Semigroup") but I'm stuck. The following is given:

```
newtype Combine a b =
  Combine { unCombine :: (a -> b) }
```

and I'm supposed to write the `Semigroup` instance for `Combine`.

And then book says that it must behave like the following:

```
 Prelude> let f = Combine $ \n -> Sum (n + 1)
 Prelude> let g = Combine $ \n -> Sum (n - 1)
 Prelude> unCombine (f <> g) $ 0
 Sum {getSum = 0}
 Prelude> unCombine (f <> g) $ 1
 Sum {getSum = 2}
 Prelude> unCombine (f <> f) $ 1
 Sum {getSum = 4}
 Prelude> unCombine (g <> f) $ 1
 Sum {getSum = 2}
```

So I first started with a **wrong solution** that type checks:

```
instance Semigroup (Combine a b) where
  Combine f <> Combine g = Combine f
```

That does not what is expected of course, but hopefully a step in the right direction. And my thinking is something like the following, in pseudocode:

```
 instance Semigroup (Combine a b) where
   (Combine f) <> (Combine g) = Combine (SOMETHING)
```

That **SOMETHING** being: `f` and `g` appended, whatever that concrete append operation is (it depends on `f` and `g`); so I think this requires `<>` from `Data.Monoid`, but I already have `import Data.Semigroup` in my code, and therefore `<>` from `Data.Monoid` coincides with the one from `Data.Semigroup`. So what am I supposed to do?

I tried to find out how I can state something like "Combine (f Monoid's <> g)", but couldn't find out.

The book also states unless I'm using GHC 8.x, I'll have to import `Semigroup` and that I might have "shadow" the `<>` from `Monoid`; but I'm struggling to find out how to have this effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What they want is probably the addition of functions. For that, type `b` needs to be a Semigroup :

```
import Data.Semigroup

newtype Combine a b =
  Combine { unCombine :: (a -> b) }

instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (Combine a b) where
  (Combine f) <> (Combine g) = Combine (\x -> f x <> g x)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can shadow `Monoid`'s `(<>)` this way:

```
import Data.Monoid hiding ((<>))
```

Then when you `import Data.Semigroup`, you will have just one `(<>)` in scope: the one from `Data.Semigroup`.

Comment: Thanks! Good to learn that! (And it already started to fee like Lisp :P)