# How to test Semigroup law for this data type?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, quickcheck

I'm trying to solve the same exercise as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456716/how-to-write-semigroup-instance-for-this-data-type) in Chapter 15 of ["Haskell Programming from First Principles"](http://haskellbook.com/). I've already made a Semigroup instance, and I'm having trouble writing the QuickCheck part of the exercise.

A Semigroup instance should satisfy:

```
a <> (b <> c) == (a <> b) <> c
```

where `<>` is the Semigroup mappend.

I have come up with the following:

```
import Data.Semigroup
import Test.QuickCheck

semigroupAssoc :: (Eq m, Semigroup m) => m -> m -> m -> Bool
semigroupAssoc a b c = (a <> (b <> c)) == ((a <> b) <> c)

newtype Combine a b = Combine { unCombine :: (a -> b) }

instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (Combine a b) where
  (Combine f) <> (Combine g) = Combine (\x -> (f x) <> (g x))

instance CoArbitrary (Combine a b) where
  coarbitrary (Combine f) = variant 0

instance (CoArbitrary a, Arbitrary b) => Arbitrary (Combine a b) where
  arbitrary = do
    f <- arbitrary
    return $ Combine f

type CombineAssoc a b = Combine a b -> Combine a b -> Combine a b -> Bool

main :: IO ()
main = do
  quickCheck (semigroupAssoc :: CombineAssoc Int Bool)
```

Everything compiles except for the `quickCheck` line, where it complains that there is `No instance for (Eq (Combine Int Bool)) arising from a use of ‘semigroupAssoc’`.

I don't think there is a way to test if two arbitrary function are equal (the functions wrapped up by `Combine`), but the exercise text suggests that such a thing is possible.

Any ideas on how I could make this work?

EDIT:

The authors give a hint for this exercise:

> Hint: This function will eventually be applied to a single value
>   of type a. But you’ll have multiple functions that can produce a
>   value of type b. How do we combine multiple values so we have
>   a single b? This one will probably be tricky! Remember that the
>   type of the value inside of Combine is that of a function. If you
>   can’t figure out CoArbitrary, don’t worry about QuickChecking
>   this one.

@Li-yao Xia's answer seems to be the best answer. But shouldn't I use this CoArbitrary instance for something?

Comment: Latest versions of QC support [functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html) but you would have to change your type - `newtype Combine' fun a b = Combine (fun a b); type Combine = Combine' (->); type Combine_Test = Combine' Fun` (or create a distinct type replicating the structure but replacing `->` with `Fun`)

Comment: While for this example they want you to use `quickCheck` on the whole, reducing functions using lambda calculus can generally prove equality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't **decide** whether two functions are equal. But you can **test** it!

Two functions are equal if and only if for any input they give the same output. This is a testable property: generate some inputs, compare the outputs. If they are different, you've got a counter-example.

```
-- Test.QuickCheck.(===) requires (Eq b, Show b)
-- but you can use (==) if you prefer.
funEquality :: (Arbitrary a, Show a, Eq b, Show b) => Combine a b -> Combine a b -> Property
funEquality (Combine f) (Combine g) =
  property $ \a -> f a === g a
```

Notice that the `Bool` result in the type of "decidable equality" `(==) :: X -> X -> Bool` is replaced with `Property` in what we might call "testable equality" `funEquality :: X -> X -> Property`. It's actually not necessary to use `property` and convert the function `a -> Property` (or `a -> Bool` if you use `(==)`) to `Property`, but the types look neater that way.

We need to rewrite the function corresponding to the associativity property, since we no longer rely on `Eq`.

```
type CombineAssoc a b = Combine a b -> Combine a b -> Combine a b -> Property

combineAssoc :: (Arbitrary a, Show a, Eq b, Show b, Semigroup b) => CombineAssoc a b
combineAssoc f g h = ((f <> g) <> h) `funEquality` (f <> (g <> h))
```

Edit: at this point we're actually still missing a `Show` instance for `Combine`. QuickCheck provides a wrapper `Fun` to both generate and show functions as counterexamples.

```
main = quickCheck $ \(Fn f) (Fn g) (Fn h) ->
  (combineAssoc :: CombineAssoc Int Bool) (Combine f) (Combine g) (Combine h)
```

Comment: That's a really good answer! But please see my edit. It seems that the authors intended to use/make a CoArbitrary instance for this type and use it to test. But how?

Comment: The hint is not suggesting making a `CoArbitrary (Combine a b)`, but rather using a `CoArbitrary a` instance to implement `Arbitrary (Combine a b)`. I implicitly use `CoArbitrary a` (on the argument type) when generating functions with `Fun` which is provided by the QuickCheck library, the hint is about how you can implement such a generator of functions.

Comment: Instead of `funEquality` function you can just use `=-=` operator from `Test.QuickCheck.Checkers` to compare any functions in the same way.

Comment: I *think* `combineAssoc` is missing a `Semigroup b`

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it is not possible or at least not feasible, however you don't really need a test case with such a big argument type as `Int`!

For smaller types, e.g. `Int16`, you can just exhaustively try all possible arguments to determine equality. The [universe package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.0/docs/Data-Universe.html) has a convenient class for that:

```
import Data.Universe

instance (Universe a, Eq b) => Eq (Combine a b) where
  Combine f == Combine g = all (\x -> f x == g x) universe
```

Then your original check will work, albeit unacceptably slow; I'd recommend changing it to `quickCheck (semigroupAssoc :: CombineAssoc Int16 Bool)`.